# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable Python

Tags: python, int

```
def parseDump(dump, partNumber):
    '''Parse dump for dynamic fields such as date, checksum, and serial and fill in with appropriate values'''
    byte = 0
    while byte < len(dump):
        if dump[byte] == 'SN':
            dump = serial(dump, byte, partNumber)
        elif dump[byte] == 'YYYYMMDD' or dump[byte] == 'YYMMDD':
            dump = date(dump, byte)
      > elif 'CC_' in dump[byte]:
            dump = checksum(dump, byte)
        byte += 1
    return dump
```

The console says the error is at the line I marked with >.

Comment: Could you paste in the exact error you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

`dump` appears to be an integer, but you seem to be expecting it to be a string. You should check whatever is calling the parseDump function to make sure that is actually sending a string.

Answer (score 0):

`dump[byte]` is obviously an int, which is not iterable. The `in` accepts something iterable.